# How to Back Up and Verify a Windows 10 System Partition on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, backup, ntfs-3g

I have a dual-boot computer running Windows 10 and Fedora 31.  I would like to image my Windows 10 partition, but am not fully comfortable with its own backup facilities.  Therefore, I am looking for a way to do this from my Fedora system.

In the past, I have successfully used partimage to image my Windows 7 systems.  I've also tried fsarchiver, but that gave (non-fatal) error messages which made me reluctant to trust it.  When I try to image my Windows 10 system with partimage, I now get two non-fatal error messages: one saying that partimage can't handle resident attributes, and the other saying it can't process $BITMAP.  I have no idea what the consequences of these errors are, so again I don't want to trust that I can recover fully from this backup.  I've tried fsarchiver, but that now gives me fatal errors.  I've tried ntfsclone, and this apparently worked; at least it generated no error messages.

But how do I know if I can recover my Windows 10 system using the ntfsclone-generated backup if I need to?  The fact that partimage now shows errors when it didn't in the past may mean that Windows 10 uses some aspects of ntfs which are new or weren't used by Windows 7; how do I know whether ntfsclone handles these aspects correctly?  I could restore the image to an unused partition, but don't know how to verify that the file systems are identical.  There is the ntfscmp utility, but that is part of the same package as ntfsclone, and therefore could have the same shortcomings (if any).

Any suggestions?

Comment: dd should be able to image the whole drive. Since it's dual boot, you might also consider a Windows imaging tool with GUI such as Macrium Reflect, and choose partitions to image. Reflect can run from an active Windows partition (even imaging that partition, using Volume Shadow Copy) or from a boot drive with WinPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ntfsclone actually performs a **block-level** copy, and the only NTFS-specific feature is that it skips clusters which are marked as "unused" in the NTFS allocation bitmap ($Bitmap file). After reading this single file, it copies all data structures without even trying to parse them. This means that ntfsclone doesn't *have* to deeply understand all new features – only the most essential ones.

What I would try is to make a full-size image using `dd`, mount it on Linux as a loop image, run `fstrim` against the mounted filesystem (which will discard unallocated clusters), then unmount and compare the trimmed "full" image against the *ntfsclone*-created image. They should be mostly identical.

You could also convert the image from 'raw' to 'VHD' (vpc) or 'VHDX' format using `qemu-img` or `vboxmanage`, then see if it can be successfully mounted on a *different* Windows 10 system. (Alternatively, attach it to a VM running Windows 10.) Then run `chkdsk` to make sure there aren't any obvious issues.

---

I have recently used the Windows `dism /create-image` tool to create a WIM-format image of the entire system partition. It is specifically meant for creating images of the OS partition (and that's also how the OS gets installed in the first place); WIM images are file-level but that should not cause any issues. You can run it from a Windows install USB stick – just minimize the installer window and hit Shift+F10 to open a command shell.